# iPhone Dev error - libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: iphone, swift

I am currently following a tutorial, but they do not mention anything on how to fix the following error.

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: What code were you running when you got this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the actions and referencing outlets of all your buttons. Make sure you get rid of the one that you do not need. This solved my error.

Thanks,